# omitting row with empty field in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe

```
seq   value
ACCCT   1
ACTGS   2
        3
ACCTC   4
```

I want to omit the rows which have an empty field in the seq column.
I tired the following but it did not work

```
   new_frame = pd.DataFrame(columns = design_frame.columns)
   for idx,row in design_frame.iterrows():
          seq = design_frame.ix[idx,'seq']

           if not seq == '':
                   new_row = design_frame.ix[idx,:]
                   new_frame = new_frame.append(new_row,ignore_index = True)


   design_frame = new_frame
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `dropna` for that if the you want to remove the empty rows:

```
df.dropna(subset=['seq'])
```

However, I think you do not have `NaN` values, but empty strings (`''`). In that case you eg do `df[df['seq']!='']`, or first convert the empty strings to `NaN` values (`df[df['seq']==''] = np.nan`)

In any case, you should try to avoid iterating over the dataframe for such cases.